# No output for select query in jdbc

Tags: java, sql, database

I am trying to find out person details by name in SQLdatabce using JDBC. Why is this not giving any output?

```
public static void DisplayByName(Connection con) throws SQLException {
        String q1 = "SELECT * FROM PERSONS WHERE NAME = ?";
        PreparedStatement pmt = con.prepareStatement(q1);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter name to find details:");
        String name = sc.next();
        pmt.setString(1,"%"+name+"%");
        ResultSet rs = pmt.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)+ " " +rs.getInt(3)+ " " +rs.getString(4) + " "
                               +rs.getString(5)+" "+rs.getString(6)+ " " +rs.getString(7)); 
              }
    }
```

Comment: Please try to change "SELECT * FROM PERSONS WHERE NAME = ?" to "SELECT * FROM PERSONS WHERE NAME LIKE ?"

Comment: use `WHERE NAME LIKE` instead of `WHERE NAME=` in your `select` query.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.